# Unable to fix signing identity issue on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, developer-tools, code-signing-certificate

I am not new to this but I am unable to fix my signing identity from Xcode Version 6.2 (6C86e). When I click **fix issue** on the following message:

[image]

I get a pop up window saying:

> "The selected team's agent, 'Name Surname' must agree to the latest
>   ios Program License Agreement.  Please visit the Member Center.
>   https://developer.apple.com/membercenter"

I went on "https://developer.apple.com" and accepted the latest iOS Program agreement. This is what I can see on my legal agreements section:

[image]

However the message on Xcode keeps popping up.. I tried loggin in and out but it does not show me the legal agreement message anymore so I assume on their server side is accepted. I wonder if this is because **iTunes connect is temporarily unavailable**.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you the team agent ?

Comment: yes.. it just solved itself after 10 minutes.. maybe some server propagation issue?

Comment: How do you accept the agreement?  It's just a link to a PDF.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

It's a propagation server issue. Wait approximately 10 minutes and it will be fixed.

Comment: Apple may have more issues this time as they seem to have changed most of the license agreements due to the new membership program...

Comment: Super annoying... Apple, thank you once again for letting your lawyers waste 15 minutes of my time.  Now that I've clicked "Accept" twice, I'm sure you're feeling that much safer from the multitude of lawsuits I was just about to file.

Comment: And I was thinking it was a server propagation issue all along... I know better now +1

Comment: Read olegiv's answer and skip the 10 min wait

Comment: @staxim You've apparently never done a fresh moderately-complex DNS setup.  Nor set up by hand a series of servers and load balancers.  Or… compiled a large C/C++/Obj-C project, for that matter.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson My point is that Apple is letting their lawyers run amok.  This is not a technical issue.  The company is not achieving anything by forcing their developers (and user base) to accept updated terms of service every few weeks.  I'm not asking them to improve their servers' data propagation time; I'm asking them to stop interrupting my work to do unnecessary things.  The 10 minute wait was just the inconvenient icing on the cake that gave me a few minutes to exercise my God-given right to complain on Stack.

Comment: i only had to wait 5 mins.

Comment: Well it's hyper annoying. It is not enough, that as a paying customer I regularly forced to agree with changing everything, it is topped with this latency, and apple internal inconsistencies.

Comment: Agreed.  It's shocking that it's 2016, and Xcode and these Agreements are still so damn developer-unfriendly.

Comment: I found an Xcode restart did the trick for me, however it could have just been this answer in disguise! Who knows...

Answer (score 26):

For me to solve this problem I had to login to http://itunesconnect.apple.com. There was a yellow banner that kindof told me what to do. I had to go to  **Contracts, Tax, and Banking** and setup the contracts there.

Comment: Actually if you had done anything to spend 10 mins it would have fixed it since as the accepted answer says, it is a propagation issue.

Comment: Did you have to set up all contracts? even the ones you don't use?

Comment: After 2017 this is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In my case the solution was:

1. Xcode: Preferences / Accounts / View Details...;
2. Click refresh (bottom left);
3. "Certificate Not Found" box pops-up with

> "Your Mac Development Certificate for “your name” was not found on the Member Center. Xcode can submit a certificate signing request on your behalf. Would you like Xcode to do so now?

4. Click Request and tick all certificates in the next screen;
5. 15 sec of waiting and the issue fixed.

Comment: The only thing from all above that worked for me. (I waited at least 30 minutes thinking this is a propagation issue, but once I did this - it immediately started working)

Comment: On the new Xcode7, they got rid of the refresh button.

Comment: This fixed it for me on XCode 6.2. I also thought it was a propagation issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case none of the answers worked - olegiv's answer came close but given that in Xcode7 Apple has removed the refresh button, that wasn't an option either.

Instead, downloading all provisioning profiles again worked: 
Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details -> Download All

Struggled with this for a while, hope that helps.

Comment: I thought this might work for me, but when I pressed the Download All button nothing happened.

Comment: Same here.  Xcode 7.1, I click on the "Download all" button, and absolutely nothing happens.  (One day, if I work hard, I'll learn to program a developer environment as professional as this..  grrr...)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me (after accepting the agreement) was removing my apple ID from the account list in Xcode and adding it back in.

Comment: Dumb question... where the heck are the Legal Agreements on the Apple Developer website ?   I'm logged in as our company's Administrator, but don't see them anywhere.  ;-(

Comment: Your Account tab -> Legal Agreements

Comment: Thanks.  Strangely, this option didn't appear earlier, now it does...  And even now, it just shows a set of links, nothing to suggest that it's waiting for us to sign-off an agreement, regardless of the message in Xcode.  (Sigh.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by running Xcode->Preferences->Accounts then selecting the agent and clicking the Create button for each of the Signing Identities