# Xcode 7.3 - Unable to fix code signing issue

Tags: xcode7.3

I am new to this Xcode and we are using 7.3 version. We had a problem in launching the app on iOS device with the Xcode after connecting my Mac to the iOS device (iPad).

I have connected my iPad to Mac and then build the solution but I have been encountered with an error message along with Fix issue button in the warning message.

If I clicked the Fix issue button then I am getting the error as:

> Unable to fix code signing issue. Xcode failed to resolve the issue. Check your code signing settings, ensure you have a matching signing certificate and provisioning profile installed; and try again

Because of this error I could not be able to run the app on my iPad device. Can you provide me a solution on how to fix this issue and make the app run in my iPad device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611750/unable-to-fix-signing-identity-issue-on-xcode Hope this one helps.